# Pillow down scale image Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to downscale an image in python.
The original image that I have is of resolution 800x800, and dpi is 72 pixels/inch.

CODE:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('AXSFZLB_1.jpg')
im.thumbnail((240,240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save('compressed.jpg', 'JPEG', progressive=True, quality=100)
```

The compressed image is blurry.
I have tried the resize function as well, but this too quiet doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to fix this?

ps - I want a high resolution thumbnail image.

Comment: There is no such thing as a high resolution thumbnail. You can either have one or the other, not both.

Comment: You also need to remember that JPG is a lossy format, so resizing/thumbnailing is never going to be perfect. Have you tried using `Image.BICUBIC` instead of `Image.ANTIALIAS`?

Comment: ya, i have tried that, but didn't work.
What i don't understand here is that -- Since, we got enough data in the bigger image, isn't there any way, we can pack more pixels into the smaller - resized image. Why does the quality degrade drastically? and how can we ever downscale an image in this case..?

Comment: «I want a high resolution thumbnail image.»

You will get the resolution you pass in `im.thumbnail` or `im.resize` function. It can be high or not, it is up to you.

Comment: Could you show exactly source image and result and maybe the result you are expected?